# Maven Unable to Find AEM Archetype

Tags: maven, aem

I've been starting at this problem for way to long... Im working through the Adobe wknd project and I can't get pass this command and most of the work is built off of it

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=com.adobe.granite.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype \
  -DarchetypeVersion=18
```

I've tried it on the VPN and off, with all possible proxy configs and still getting the same error of

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.adobe.granite.archetypes:aem-project-archetype:18)
```

Deleting and reinstalling multiple times. Different networks and proxy configs as well Mac OS.

`mvn -v` returns

```
Maven home: /Users/dmills/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.1
Java version: 1.8.0_212, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Get this error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.adobe.granite.archetypes:aem-project-archetype:18)
```

Build is failing and I don't know where to go now

Comment: I've been staring at this for way too long as well and abandoned it, but now I'm trying again. I'm getting BUILD FAILURE too every time. The "Getting Started" Chapter 1, step 2 instructions state to "Create Maven Archetype", but it fails using Command, PowerShell and Git Bash. In Command, I'm running this from C:\> and tried from another newly-created directory, but it always fails. All prerequisites are installed (Maven, Java, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error indicates that there is no Maven repository configured that contains the archetype you want to use. Default Maven installations are not aware of the Adobe repository which contains the archetype. You have to configure the repository.

Usually, you should use the following repository for your AEM projects:

```
http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public
```

This repository contains the archetype you want to use:

https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/adobe/granite/archetypes/aem-project-archetype/18/

Based on the documentation (see Links below) this would be a minimal Maven `settings.xml` that would allow you to use the AEM Maven archetype:

```
<settings 
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
  https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>adobe-public</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <releaseRepository-Id>adobe-public-releases</releaseRepository-Id>
        <releaseRepository-Name>Adobe Public Releases</releaseRepository-Name>
        <releaseRepository-URL>http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public</releaseRepository-URL>
      </properties>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>adobe-public-releases</id>
          <name>Adobe Basel Public Repository</name>
          <url>http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>adobe-public-releases</id>
          <name>Adobe Basel Public Repository</name>
          <url>http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Note: I set `activeByDefault` to `true` for the `adobe-public` profile. This way you do not need to pass `-Padobe-public` on the command line to activate the profile.

Now, if you run the following command you should be able to use the archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=com.adobe.granite.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype \
  -DarchetypeVersion=18
```

**Links**:

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/SetUpTheAdobeMavenRepository.html

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: Setting activeByDefault to true made it work for me. Thanks.

Though how would the -Padobe-public attribute would work? Would that be part of the mvn archetype:generate command?

Answer (score 0):

In the Adobe profile the 'settings' xml tag is missing:

```
<settings 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

 <profiles>
     <profile>

      .....

     </profile>
   </profiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update the settings.xml file in the m2 folder. Please look into the below link if you are using archtype 13 and 6.4

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/maven_arch13.html

Also in the profile tag please update the adobe repo url to 'https' instead of http.